# Php regex to match string containing underscore or followed by a digit

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a scenario like this :

```
 a) word  => capture "word"
 b) word_and_digit_90 => capture "word_and_digit" and "90"
 c) word_90 => capture "word" and 90
```

I have regexp like this which is good with case a) and c) but failing with b)

```
 /([a-z]+)(?:_(\d+)){0,1}/i
```

I appreciate if someone would suggest a solution for a), b), c)

## edit

One suggested solution is :

```
 /([a-z]+(?:_[a-z]+){0,})(?:_(\d+)){0,1}/i
```

I would like if someone suggest good alternative

Comment: I just tested this and it works for all 3.  Also, why the trailing `/i`?

Comment: `{0,1}` can be shortened to `?`.

Comment: @Jack , that means that trailing digit can only appear once or none

Comment: @sakhunzi - yes, so does `?`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/([a-z_]+[a-z])(?:_(\d+))?/
```

Answer (score 0):

Most simple:

```
/^[a-z]+[_a-z\d]+$/
```

Comment: that will only match the string , I was in need to capture groups